# How can i route request to specific views according to parameters in Django?

Tags: python, django

I created an API with Django and i am trying to route requests to different views for optimization purposes.

Here is what i'm trying to do: if the GET request is `127.0.0.1:8000/api/sales/?key=<KEY>&some_query=<some_value>&...` that query should be handled by a view called `sales`. If the GET request contains a specific parameter called `sale_value` the request should be routed to another view called `large_sales`, for example `127.0.0.1:8000/api/sales/?key=<KEY>&sale_value=<INT>...` should be handled from the `large_sales` view.

Here is what i tried:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('sales/', views.sales, name="sales"),
    path('sales/sale_value<int:num>', views.large_sales, name="large_sales"),
]
```

This will route all the requests to `sales`. How can i do this? Maybe with regex?

Edit: i can't handle this logic directly in the view because i want to cache these two queries with different TTL. Example:

```
@cache_page(1.5)
def sales(request):
...


@cache_page(10)
def large_sales(request):
...
```

Comment: Could you use kwargs to handle the parameters rather than query params? If not just handle what you do based on 'sale_vale' parameter inside the one view?

Comment: Handling this in the view was the perfect solution but i don't think it's possible because i basically need to use two different caches according to the query (see my edit)

Comment: Siva was quick lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sales(request):
    try:
        sale_value = request.GET['sale_value']
    except:
        return redirect(large_sales, num=11) # replace 11 with your number.
```

or try to use if condition (`if sale_value != None:`)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a view which accesses request.GET and redirects accordingly.

You may also need to put defensive code in the view that you redirect to, to make sure that a user (or attacer) is not getting creative with completely insecure GET parameters!

With a class-based view you can subclass get ...

```
class SalesView( some_CBV_class):
    ...

    def get( self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         if request.GET.get( 'sale_value', None):
             target = reverse('app:large_sales', kwargs={...} 
                  ) + '?' + request.GET.urlencode()
             return HttpResponseRedirect( target)
         return super().get( request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and for safety, maybe

```
class LargeSalesView( ...)

    def get( self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         if request.GET.get( 'sale_value', None) is None
             target = reverse('app:sales', kwargs={...} 
                  ) + '?' + request.GET.urlencode()
             return HttpResponseRedirect( target)
         return super().get( request, *args, **kwargs)
```